# robots.txt is making that google donst see my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-search, robots.txt

i have just finshed the site [signum.team](http://signum.team) but google is not indexing it, it says that "there is no information available because of robots.txt". but that is weird because i have the robots.txt saying:
`User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /`

[signum.team/robots.txt](http://signum.team/robots.txt)

so that should let google see everything. i did this 2 days ago and i have seen online that google should see it in a day. so does someone know what i can do to make sure google sees it?

Comment: You can use [Google's own tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en) to ensure your site is visible to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the source code of your website:

meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow'

You're forcing Google to not index your page / website, please either remove it or replace it with index from noindex so it should look like this;

meta name='robots' content='index,follow'

Comment: did it now i am going to wait to see if tomorrow it will make a diffrence

Comment: Sure, you can use webmaster tool to get it indexed instantly.

Comment: they say that there is now no information and i need to check it later D:

Comment: Add your site under webmaster, and go under fetch url, and force google to index your website. Google is so quick at indexing sites if you force them.

Answer (score 2):

Login to your WordPress site with **admin access**.

Go to `Settings > Reading` and under
Search Engine Visibility uncheck the box and you are now good to go.

Because if this box is checked it adds following code and as a result Google or any search engin cannot read your site.

`<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />`

Cheers.

Comment: ok, @LeondenBoer, no problem, but if it helps you then do up vote the answer so that other can benefit from this.